# Excel Find&Replace not working as expected

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm pretty baffled by this, I've never had any issues with a simple find&replace before. I'm just trying to replace FindValue with ReplaceValue, but it's not found. Is it because it's trying to search in "Formulas"? I don't see any other option in the drop down though.

[image: Simple search won't return the result]

[image: Can't choose anything but "formula"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be the format options you have used.
It should be "No Format Set" instead of "`Preview*`". You can achieve this by click on the button "`Format...`" -> "`Clear Find Format`"

With the format option activated, you also defined that the cell you search for has the text value "FindValue" ***and*** some cell attributes (date format or currency format etc.)

[image]